# How do you chain matching statements in cakephp 3.3.13

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I have a table in client-side that displays data using st-table. When doing filtering operation, I use the st-pipe plugin. The client side will pass an ajax get request like the following:

```
search= {"assigned_to.user_info.full_name":"alonso","created_by.user_info.full_name":"buena"}
```

This is passed to the server and a controller handles it and generates an array:

```
$matchingStatements = [
  'AssignedTos.UserInfos' => [
    'OR' => [
        "UserInfos.firstname LIKE" => "%alonso%",
        "UserInfos.lastname LIKE"  => "%alonso%"
    ]
  ],
  'CreatedBies.UserInfos' => [
    'OR' => [
        "UserInfos.firstname LIKE" => "%buena%",
        "UserInfos.lastname LIKE"  => "%buena%"
    ]
  ]
];
```

by doing this, the number of filter statements is dynamic.
This $matchingStatements will be run in a foreach loop where in each pass it will call the $leads->matching(...) statement like the following:

```
$userFields = [
    'fields' => ['id', 'username'],
    'UserInfos' => ['fields' => ['user_id', 'firstname', 'lastname']]
];
$option = [
    'contain' => [
        'Contacts',
        'AssignedTos' => $userFields,
        'LeadTypes',
        'LeadStatuses',
        'Sources',
        'PropertyRequirements' => ['Locations', 'PropertyCategories', 'Listings'],
        'Activities',
        'Events',
        'CreatedBies'=> $userFields,
        'UpdatedBies'=> $userFields
    ]
];

$leads = $leadsTable->find('all', $option);

foreach ($matchingStatements as $target=>$where) {
  $leads = $leads->matching($target, function ($q) use ($where) {
    return $q->andWhere($where);
  });
}
...
}
```

However, it seems that $leads only becomes the result of calling matching with $matchingStatements[0] only.
So the second matching which is matching('CreatedBies.UserInfos') ... is not applied.

the sample output looks the like the following json:

```
"leads": [
{
    "id": 1,
    "created_by": {
        "id": 327,
        "username": "Cedric61",
        "user_info": {
            "firstname": "Buena",
            "lastname": "Causey",
            "full_name": "Buena Causey"
        }
    },
    "assigned_to": {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Grigsby1995",
        "user_info": {
            "firstname": "Alonso",
            "lastname": "Stauffer",
            "full_name": "Alonso Stauffer"
        }
    },
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "created_by": {
        "id": 327,
        "username": "Cedric61",
        "user_info": {
            "firstname": "Buena",
            "lastname": "Causey",
            "full_name": "Buena Causey"
        }
    },
    "assigned_to": {
        "id": 2,
        "username": "ccp123",
        "user_info": {
            "firstname": "Christoper",
            "lastname": "Pedros",
            "full_name": "Christoper Pedros"
        }
    },
}
];
```

But it's suppose to output the first object only.

Any ideas on how I should be able to get the result I want is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Update:
I updated the foreach loop to the following thanks to @JohnWayne:

```
    foreach ($matchingStatements as $target=>$where) {
        $leads = $leads->innerJoinWith($target, function ($q) use ($where) {
            return $q->andWhere($where);
        });
    }
```

When outputing $leads->sql(), it shows both inner join are called but for the second one, it doesn't apply the where() conditions:

```
...
FROM 
    leads Leads 
INNER JOIN 
    users AssignedTos 
ON 
    AssignedTos.id = (Leads.user_id) 
    INNER JOIN 
        user_infos UserInfos 
    ON 
        (UserInfos.firstname like :c0 AND AssignedTos.id = (UserInfos.user_id)) 
INNER JOIN 
    users CreatedBies 
ON 
    CreatedBies.id = (Leads.created_by_id) 
INNER JOIN 
    contacts Contacts
...
```

The AssignedTos join check for the condition but does not in CreatedBies join.

What else am I missing?

Update 2:

If I manually change the sql to the following and run it manually on shell the query is what i expected i just don't know how to do this i cakephp:

```
...
    FROM 
        leads Leads 
    INNER JOIN 
        users AssignedTos
    ON 
        AssignedTos.id = (Leads.user_id) 
    INNER JOIN 
        users CreatedBies 
    ON 
        CreatedBies.id = (Leads.created_by_id) 
INNER JOIN 
    user_infos AS AssignedTosUserInfos
ON 
    (AssignedTosUserInfos.firstname like '%tamara%' AND AssignedTos.id = (AssignedTosUserInfos.user_id))
INNER JOIN
    user_infos AS UpdatedBiesUserInfos
ON
    (UpdatedBiesUserInfos.firstname like '%gertude%' AND UpdatedBies.id = (UpdatedBiesUserInfos.user_id))   
INNER JOIN
    user_infos AS CreatedBiesUserInfos
ON
    (CreatedBiesUserInfos.firstname like '%gertude%' AND CreatedBies.id = (CreatedBiesUserInfos.user_id))
INNER JOIN 
    contacts Contacts 
ON 
    Contacts.id = (Leads.contact_id) 
...
```

Comment: "_it seems_" isn't an overly meaningful statement. Have you debugged that `matching()` is actually being invoked more than once? Have you debugged the generated query? What does it look like? What does the final matching map look like (`$query->eagerLoader()->matching()`)? Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version - thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ndb, i have an update in the question. Hope you can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$leads = $leadsTable->find('all', $option);
```

Then collect all where conditions in one list

```
$myList = [];
foreach ($matchingStatements as $key => $val) {
  $myList[$key] = $val;
}
```

Then make one time matching

```
  $leads->matching($target, function ($q) use ($myList) {
    return $q->andWhere(['myField IN' => $myList]);
  });
```

If you have more relations than instead ->matching use ->innerJoinWith like

```
$leads->innerJoinWith('TableName', function ($q) {
    return $q->where(['TableName.FieldName IN' => 'conditions']);
});
```

and so on

More info [Cakephp 3.x Inner Join With](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith)

Comment: Will this work for other association path. for example: Contacts.Address.country, PropertyRequirements.Range.beds_min

Comment: You can also use inner join... I wull update answer with an example

Comment: Doesn't seem to work still. I already tried using inner join and it still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution, I'm just not sure if it's elegant.
I decided to use join() method and build the sql join manually.
when the client-side passes the search predicates, it converts it to an array that would declare the following sql foreach of the predicate found:

```
...    
INNER JOIN 
        associated_table AssociatedTable
    ON 
        AssociatedTable.id = (MainTable.user_id) 
    INNER JOIN 
        deeper_table AS AssociatedTableDeeperTable
    ON 
        (AssociatedTableDeeperTable.field like '%something%' AND AssociatedTable.id = (AssociatedTableDeeperTable.user_id))
...
```

and add it to an array of predicate to be passed to join(...):

```
$myJoins = [];
foreach ( ... ) {
    $search_text = ... //taken from client-side passed data
    $table = ... // table = 'AssociatedTable' take from client-side passed data that has been normalized
    $myJoins[$table] = [
        'table'      => 'associated_table',
        'type'       => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => "$table.id = main_table.id"
    ];
    $myJoins["{$table}DeeperTable"] = [
        'table'      => 'deeper_table',
        'type'       => 'INNER',
        'conditions' => "({$table}DeeperTable.firstname LIKE '%{$search_text}%' AND $table.id = ({$table}DeeperTable.user_id))"
    ];
}

$leads = $leadsTable->find('all',...)
if (count($myJoins)>0) {
    $leads->join($myJoins);
}
```

If anybody have better answer, it would be good to know.
Thanks!

Comment: Without further information this looks like a possible SQL injection vulnerability. While you may have precautions in place somewhere else in your code, I'd advise to avoid such constructs at all costs, and also not put them up as examples, as inexperienced users may just copy them!

Answer (score 0):

### SQL injection vulnerabilities

First things first. From your example it's not clear what exactly your controller does to build the conditions array, so I'd like to note that it's very important to apply whitelisting or similar techniques when dealing with user supplied table/column names, as the keys in a `key => value` conditions array are being inserted into the query as-is!

### Use unique association aliases

Judging from the SQL output, the problem are the non-unique `UserInfos` association aliases, you cannot include one and the same alias more than once, the query-builder does not have any auto-rename functionality or similar.

If you want to be able to use the shorthand matching and/or joining methods, then you could fix the problem by renaming the associations to something similar to what you've shown in your working SQL example, like `AssignedTosUserInfos`, `CreatedBiesUserInfos`, etc.

```
// ...

class AssignedTosTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        // ...

        $this->belongsTo('AssignedTosUserInfos', [
            'className' => 'UserInfos'
        ]);
    }
}
```

The conditions array would ofcourse need to be changed accordingly:

```
$matchingStatements = [
    'AssignedTos.AssignedTosUserInfos' => [
        'OR' => [
            "AssignedTosUserInfos.firstname LIKE" => "%alonso%",
            "AssignedTosUserInfos.lastname LIKE"  => "%alonso%"
        ]
    ],
    // ...
];
```

#### Dynamic association aliases for shared tables

In case you do not have concrete table classes for the `AssignedTos`, `CreatedBies`, etc associations, and you're using a shared `UsersTable` class, you could create the association alias dynamically using the current tables alias, that way a proper association is created depending on the alias set for the parent association:

```
// ...

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        // ...

        $this->belongsTo($this->registryAlias() . 'UserInfos', [
            'className' => 'UserInfos'
        ]);
    }
}
```

If the parent, ie the `LeadsTable` class, would create the association like:

```
$this->belongsTo('AssignedTos', [
    'className' => 'Users'
]);
```

then the above, dynamic association in the `UsersTable` class would be named `AssignedTosUserInfos`. For the `CreatedBies` association it would be `CreatedBiesUserInfos`, and so on.